# Project Euler #3 STUCK

Tags: c#

I really didn't want it to come to this, the point of course of PE is that I should try to solve the problems myself.

The first two I managed in less than an hour, unfortunately I am completely stuck on problem 3.  Now I have tried the traditional method of division by trial, of course this is too slow, I've tried to optimize the division by trial by dividing by *sqrt(n)* but it is still way too slow to get the highest prime factor of 600,851,475,143.

Now I've even tried to use the *Sieve of Eratosthenes* for this, which I have to admit I barely understand, but it's still not cutting it, first of all the amount of "marked" numbers causes an exception to be thrown because the amount of entries becomes gigantic when you try to generate all primes up to 600,851,475,143.

I'm stuck and quite frankly I'm in a place wher eI'm starting to get annoyed with this right now..

Here's my code:

```
class Program
    {
        // The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
        // What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(GetHighestPrimeFactor(600851475143).ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static List<long> GeneratePrimeNumbers(long n)
        {
            // Let's use the Sieve of Eratosthenes for this
            var markedNumbers = new List<long>();
            var primes = new List<long>();

            for (long i = n / 2; i < n; i++)
            {
                // If this is false then this is a prime number, add it to the list of primes
                if (!markedNumbers.Contains(i)) 
                {
                    primes.Add(i);

                    for (long j = i; j <= n; j+= i)
                    {
                        markedNumbers.Add(j);
                    }
                }
            }

            return primes;
        }

        static long GetHighestPrimeFactor(long n)
        {
            var primes = GeneratePrimeNumbers(n);

            // Loop backwards and return when we hit the first prime number
            for (long i = n / 2; i > 1; i--)
            {
                if (n % i == 0)
                {
                    if (primes.Contains(i))
                    {
                        return i;
                    }
                }
            }

            //Code should not reach this point of execution
            return -1;
        }
```

Comment: You might start with "I am trying to write a program that finds the largest prime factor of a given arbitrary number".  Otherwise everything else you are saying has no context of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: If you were to somehow find the smallest prime factor of a number, think about how that would help you reduce the search space for the other prime factors.

Answer (score 2):

> the point of course of PE is that I should try to solve the problems myself.

Right, so here are some hints rather than an answer.

> I've tried to optimize the division by trial by dividing by sqrt(n)

I don't see how that helps. Suppose you are trying to find the largest prime factor of 74. The square root of 74 is 8 point something. How does dividing 74 by 8.something help?

> Now I've even tried to use the Sieve of Eratosthenes for this

The Sieve is for finding prime numbers. Is your theory that you're going to find all the prime numbers up to the desired number and then of those find the biggest that divides the number?

That's going to be too computationally expensive for a large number.

So here are your hints:

- If a number n > 0 is prime then it is its own largest prime divisor.
- If a number n > 0 is is composite then it is x * y where neither are 1.
- One of those two numbers is less than or equal to the square root of n.
- The largest prime factor of n is equal to either the largest prime factor of x or the largest prime factor of y.

If you don't understand why one of these facts is true, **stop and think about it hard until you do**. You'll never get anywhere on the next few Euler problems unless you've got this down cold.

Now with those hints you should be able to break the problem down into a sequence of smaller problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have read about Sieve of Eratosthenes myself but I don't know much about techniques for prime factorization.  I'm not sure that beginning with generating the list of all known primes is a good technique for this.  Not saying it's bad, I just suspect that **maybe** more practical techniques don't take that approach, as it would have huge space requirements.

So that aside, I will suggest some fixes for the memory usage problem of your list of primes.

For one I would write the results of GeneratePrimeNumbers to segmented files instead of adding them to inmemory lists, each file covering some block of primes(fairly large but within the confines of what is easily loaded into memory).  Perhaps as the first line some info about largest/smallest prime in the file.

In GeneratePrimeNumbers begin with the page holding the largest primes(loading just that page from the file into a list, choose a C# data type that has O(1) time for .Contains, I think a HashSet would be good for this), as you work backwards and cross to a new segment, remove the list of current page of primes and load the new page of primes.   This will solve your memory usage issue.  If you make sure each page contains the same number of primes(or max number since last page will probably be partial) then you can either reuse existing list or initialize the list with a Capacity == to the size of the page.  Whatever data strcture you go with, it probably has a capacity option in the constructor, and you want to pass this as it will ensure it requests the amount of memory needed up front.  If you have 300 primes, and did not set capcity, then what happens is the internal array size of the list doubles as you add to it.  When it crosses 256 for example, it creates a new 512 item array internally and copies the 256 items to the new size 512 array.  this means when crossing such a boundary, the list is using three times the amount of memory because it has both the old array and the new array which is 2 times the old array.  After the copy completes it doesn't need the old array.  Point being, if you don't set capacity up front, then you will potentially get out of memory exceptions when you only need roughly a 3rd of free memory.

I would probably have GeneratePrimeNumbers just check for pre-existing files, and if the number passed in is larger, then just skip to the largest existing page and write additional pages up to that value.  I might have an index file that list the pages and there start/end primes so that you don't have to read a bunch of large files to perform this check, but I think you can get by with just having the start/end in each file as the first line and only reading the first line then closing the file.